# mp4v and mp4a in Ubuntu VLC

Tags: vlc, ffmpeg, mp4

In 13.10, I have this error in VLC:

```
[0x7f529c0038a0] main decoder error: no suitable decoder module for fourcc `mp4v'. VLC probably does not support this sound or video format.
[0x7f529c004470] main decoder error: no suitable decoder module for fourcc `mp4a'. VLC probably does not support this sound or video format.
```

I thought that Ubuntu supported all the latest codecs.

Is there a way to fix this? Or even a way to convert my video for use? I imagine that it could have to do with ffmpeg, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Handbrake-gtk :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

This program can help you converting Mp4v and Mp4a to Mp4 .

[image]

Image reference [Here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_qBN_dFzAuCo/TL_Cw-stIcI/AAAAAAAAB3s/YbESKR0DQrE/s1600/HandBrake-on-ubuntu-linux.png)

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found